# SpringBoot on Open JDK 11 - 'ClassNotFound' errors when SecurityManager is active

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to upgrade my Spring Boot project to use Java 11,
I'm compiling the project to a jar and I'm trying to run it with:

```
java -jar ./myApp.jar
```

When running, I begin receiving errors such as:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/home/user/dev/my-app/target/my-app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/user/myapp/encryption/EnableEncryptedProps.class];
```

The full stack trace is here: https://pastebin.com/LZmVgwXS

With that in mind, when I'm starting my app, I'm enabling the default SecurityManager.
When I don't, the app works just fine - but I want to address the actual problem and fix it properly without getting rid of the SecurityManager.

This is how I start my app:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager()); // When this line is removed - all is working fine
    SpringApplication.run(Initializer.class, args);
}
```

Comment: Can you run with `-Djava.security.debug="access,failure"` to see if there are permission checks failing?

Comment: What is the spring boot version?

Comment: The root cause seems to be `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.user.myapp.common.ContentRangeConverter`. How is the class made available to the App? Does this work fine with JDK8?

Comment: @Neo Yep, it works well on JDK8.

Comment: @JonathanJohx 2.1.0

Comment: @AlanBateman I ran and the result is exactly the same, ran a diff of the two logs and they're pretty much identical :/

Comment: I have the same problem. My springboot application just can't find all of the application classes when I enabled jvm security manager with allow all permission. `-Djava.security.debug` shows all the access are allowed. Remove the `-Djava.security.manager`, the application will startup without any issue. One solution I found is if I unzip the application jar, and run with `java -Djava.security.manager  -Djava.security.policy=./global.policy   org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher `, it works fine.

Comment: I also have the same problem and can confirm that it only occurs with security-manager + JDK11. If I disable security-manager of use JDK8 the error goes away. Also with java.security.debug I only get "access allowed" messages logged but no failure/error.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute 'basePackageClasses' is of type NoClassDefFoundError, but Class[] was expected in attributes for annotation [org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan]
---
Also sounds like a bug in springs error handling - returning an exception as result?

Comment: Error occurs with active security manager and with both openjdk 11.0.2 2019-01-15 and AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11).

Answer (score 1):

I have been investigating this as part of [this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17796). It appears to be caused by a combination of poor diagnostics and exception handling in in the JDK and a bug in Spring Boot.

When the security manager is enabled, the JDK performs some additional jar checking. This jar checking fails with a `NullPointerException` during an attempt to load a class file. Unfortunately, the exception is swallowed so the resulting symptom is that a class could not be loaded but with no indication of why it could not be loaded.

The bug in Spring Boot is what causes a variable to be `null` in the first place.
Until it is addressed, you can work around the problem by disabling the additional jar checking using a system property:

```
-Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true
```